# Images not loading in all Stack Exchange websites

Tags: support, bug, images

I just started noticing (I don't remember when it started) that all the images (profile pictures, uploading images, basically all images with a i.stack.imgur link) won't load. I originally asked the question [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1356016), but I still haven't solved it. I checked using my other laptops and still the problem persists (even in my phone). At this point, I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask the question. I also tried using mobile data but still won't load the images. Here are some screenshots of the problem:

[image: Profile picture not loading]

[image: Uploaded image not loading]

[image: Error message]

Comment: Have you checked if there's a firewall where you are?

Comment: Are you using VPN? Are you located in a region that blocks imgur (see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385165/8967612))? Do other imgur links (that don't have the `stack` subdomain) work for you?

Comment: Try disabling extensions and check if cache is present

Comment: Okay I just tried going to Stack Exchange with a VPN, and now everything’s loading. I guess it’s just blocked in my current region. Thanks for the help, guys!